# How to resolve versionConflict error in Termsteel (PyJWT, flask-jwt-login and argon2-cffi)?

Tags: python, conflicting-libraries, pyjwt, argon2-cffi

Hi I have a problem whit python packet conflict except that the problem is not so simple, it is not enough just to solve this conflict. **I don't want to change my code, what can I do?**

Error :

```py
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested PyJWT==2.4.0
    flask-jwt-login 0.0.5 depends on PyJWT==1.6.4

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Indeed, if I solve this problem another module would not work anymore such as argon2-cffi==21.3.0

I have given below the list of packets in the package that make my project work (including dependencies). I hope that someone could give me a solution so that I can install everything correctly without anything not working ...

My deps requirements.txt :

```
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
bidict==0.22.0
certifi==2022.5.18.1
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Argon2==0.2.0.0
flask-jwt-login==0.0.5
Flask-SocketIO==5.2.0
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.11.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
markup==0.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.4.0
python-engineio==4.2.1
python-socketio==5.4.0
requests==2.27.1
urllib3==1.26.9
waitress==2.1.2
Werkzeug==1.0.1
zipp==3.8.0
```

Here is also a link to the code and all the files : https://github.com/afi-dev/Termsteel

Thank you for any help you may offer